# saving object to database c#

Tags: c#, database, class, sqlconnection

I'm having class Report and class Program, what I want to accomplish (no luck so far) is to send data from class Program and method SaveRep() to class Report method Save() and save it in this method.

I apologize if the question is badly formulated, I am really stuck at this, please help. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Application
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        //call method SaveRep
    }

    public void SaveRep(...)
    {
       int RepID = 1;
       string Data1 = "SomeData1"
       string Data2 = "SomeData2"

       //This method should send the data above to method Save() in Report class
       //data to this method will be provided from another method.
    }        
  }

  public class Report
  {
    private static int _repID;
    public int RepID
    {
        get { return _repID; }
        set { _repID = value; }
    }

    private static string _data1;       
    public string Data1
    {
        get { return _data1; }
        set { _data1 = value; }
    }

    private static string __data2;
    public string Data1
    {
        get { return _data2; }
        set { _data2 = value; }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        string strConnectionString = (@"server=(local)\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;database=DataBase");

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        // This method should save  all data (RepID,Data1,Data2)
        // to the DB, provided to her by SaveRep method from Program class.
        // Properties are columns from a database
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no question here. Try to make some progress and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: My question is how to send dataobject from SaveRep() to save() and save it to db.If someone have any example that will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Save()
{
  string yourConnString="Replace with Your Database ConnectionString";
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnString))
  {    
     string sqlStatement = "INSERT Table1(Data1) VALUES(@Data1)";
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
     {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data1",Data1);
       //add more parameters as needed  and update insert query

        try
        {
           connection.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //log error
        }    
     }
  }
 }
```

Assuming your `Data1` is the name of your Column name. Update the sqlStatement to have your relevant columns.

Now in `SaveRep`, you can call it like

```
 public void SaveRep()
 {
   Report objReport=new Report();
   objReport.Data1="Something somethinng";
   objReport.Save();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, i get this part in Save() method, but how to provide data from SaveRep() method to her?.

Comment: @DareDevil: I added that to the answer

Comment: Oh, i didnt saw it.Thanks ;) ,

Answer (score 0):

```
    string connectionString = ....; //adjust your connection string

    string queryString = "INSERT INTO ....;"; //Adjust your query
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection))
        {
        connection.Open();
        command .ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One tiny thing that the previous speakers have not noticed, is that your `Report` class is severely broken. Why did you use `static` keywords on the variables? Do not do that! Well, unless you know what it does, and here I have the feeling you don't. Update your Report class to look like this:

```
public class Report
{
    public int RepID {get;set;}
    public string Data1 {get;set;}
    public string Data2 {get;set;}

    public void Save()
    {
        // what others said
    }
}
```

'static' in your original code makes all te variables global/shared. That means that if you'd create 500 Report objects with `new`, they all would have the same one ID, Data1 and Data2. Any change to any single of those 500 objects would cause all the objects to change. But it's be misleading, the objects would not change. They would simply have the **same** data. Looking at the "ID" field, I think you'd rather want a separate objects with separate data for separate records..