# Putting data from a register form to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have a register form (I'm working with ASP.NET MVC) and I am trying to parse the content of every field to my database but I don't really know how to do this.

First of all I don't know where I should put the connection with my database. Should it be inside my register controller? Sorry if it sound a little silly but I'm new to all this stuff! The code below is from my register-form view

```
@model Client.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.postcode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.postcode, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.female, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.female, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.male, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.male, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Υποβολή" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: This is basic question and you should do some research around this, for example - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are form's action attribute value is set to "Register/Register" . That means when you submit the form, the form will be posted to the HttpPost Register action method in RegisterController. Since you already have a class which you are using to render the input fields in the form, you can use that as the parameter type of your action method so that when the form is posted, the default model binder can map the form data to the properties of an object of that class.

So your HttpPost method will look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
  var name = model.Name;
  // to do : Save and redirect 
}
```

Now, to save data, you can read different property values of your model object (ex: `model.Name`) and use that to insert to your db. There are a lot of different options to do that like using pure ado.net code [with SqlConnection and ExecuteNonQuery method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12186505/40521) or using an ORM library like [Entity framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) or Hibernate etc. Remember, the choice is yours. **There is no such rule says that you should always use entity framework with your MVC application**.

> Should it be inside my register controller?

You will see a lot of samples/tutorials has code inside the controllers to save data to the db. The code will work. Is it a good practice ? Probably not ! It is always a good idea to move the data access code to a separate class/layer/project and call that from wherever needed.

If you are a total newbie to MVC and the concept of saving data to db. I suggest to  simply put your code in your controller itself (like those tutorials have) and make it work. Once you are successful in that, you can consider refactoring it by moving to another class/layer following the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).